# calling https web service methods

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2005, web-reference, credentialscache

I have added a **web reference** of a web service which url starts with **https**. And trying to call by the following C# code

```
testwebservices.BasicHttpBinding_GDataService webservice = new testwebservices.BasicHttpBinding_GDataService ();
Uri uri = new Uri(webservice.Url);            
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(uri, "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainName"));
webservice.Credentials = cache;

var response = webservice.GetMethods();
return response;
```

I am getting the following error

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

I guess the reason is "BasicHttpSecurityMode has not been set as Transport" (which is possible if i add as service reference). I could not find any way to set that. Or this cannot be not achievable? This is a VS.Net 2005 project,

**Updated:**
I have also add the following but still having the same error

```
webservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true
var response = webservice.GetMethods();
```

**working version** : The following code started to work. Thanks to @user469104

```
testwebservices.BasicHttpBinding_GDataService webservice = new testwebservices.BasicHttpBinding_GDataService ();
webservice.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var response = webservice.GetMethods();
```

Comment: `NetworkCredential` have you tried passing the `Domain, username, Password` instead of just `username , password`
actually I think I see your problem you need to add this line 
`webservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have tried with domain name and setting true for UseDefaultCredentials, still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is not related to https per se. The 401 means that whatever credentials are making it through to the server, if any, are not authorized to access the service.

I am guessing this is a web service hosted by IIS? If so, and you have control over it, verify that 'Integrated Authentication' is enabled (I am assuming this is what you are trying to use since you are specifying 'negotiate') and make sure you are passing valid credentials. As DJ KRAZE said in his comment, if you are trying to pass domain credentials, make sure you are also passing the domain.

Comment: Does it mean the code is al-right? If I add the service as Service Reference and use the same credential it works, but adding as Web Reference and using the above code getting the unauthorized error.

Comment: Try webservice.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainName") instead of using the credentials cache

Comment: Thanks mate. It is working now. Please check my updated question to find the working version of the code